# How to install libraries with C# on VS Community with single command line?

Tags: c#, firebase, installation, command, vs-community-edition

I am currently creating a C# Windows Form App and want to use a firebase external library from github called FirebaseDatabase.net (link is here: https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet). The issue is that I cannot download it as a zip file, and do not know where to use the command line to install the library. I have researched and opened the console using a combination ctrl+alt+o, but cannot type anything in that console since it only displays output.
The installation command line is

```
// Install release version
Install-Package FirebaseDatabase.net
```

I need help knowing where to enter this, as I really need Firebase to work with my app. I am a beginner to this.

Comment: As seen from that link, if you want to use `Install-Package`, it's ran from the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio. You can show the panel from View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console.

Comment: Thank you so much! It installed now!!